# Can i do a join and subquery with aggregation functions in a linq to sql C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Currently I have my sql statement working fine, but I need to move it to a linq statement

```
select id_matter, COUNT(id_matter) 
from Matter m 

left join ClavT cl1 
on cl1.matter_id = m.id_matter

where m.plan_id = 12 and


    cl1.valuex in (

        select valuex from ClavT c1
        where c1.matter_id = 35
    )

group by id_matter

order by COUNT(id_matter) desc
```

at this moment i have

```
var innerQuery = from c in context.ClavT where c.matter_id == matter.id_matter select c.valuex;

var query = from m in context.Matter
                join c in context.ClavT on m.id_matter equals c.matter_id into mc
                where innerQuery.Contains(c)

                select m;
```

But i cant see `c` in `query` :

```
Error   19  The name 'c' does not exist in the current context
```

And I still missing the aggregation

i want return a objet with the entity and the count of these like

```
     select new
        {
             m
            ,count(m) // maybe???
        }
     ).ToList();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the inner query needed?
couldn't you just have:

```
select id_matter, COUNT(id_matter) 
from Matter m 
left join ClavT cl1 
on cl1.matter_id = m.id_matter
where m.plan_id = 12 and c1.matter_id = 35
group by id_matter
order by COUNT(id_matter) desc
```

and

```
var query = from m in context.Matter
            join c in context.ClavT 
              on m.id_matter equals c.matter_id into mc
            from c in mc.DefaultIfEmpty() //Left Join
            where m.plan_id == 12 && c.matter_id == 35

            select m;

var mattercount = query.Count();
```